# WooCommerce prevents user from accessing CiviCRM menus

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home, evaluating-civicrm, woocommerce

I have CiviCRM installed on WordPress.

I have duplicated the wordpress Subscriber role (using Members plugin), and then I go to Administer > User and Permissions > Permissions (Access Control) > Wordpress Access Control and I assign ALL permissions to this new role.

I then assign this role to a user, and login with the user.

If I have the WooCommerce plugin activated, the user can not access the CiviCRM menus at https://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM ... it gets redirected to the WooCommerce my-account page.

As soon as I disable the WooCommerce plugin, the user now has full access to the CiviCRM menus.

Any thoughts or ideas on how to get around this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found this to be problematic as well.

You can restore the default Woo admin bar and admin access with code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_disable_admin_bar', 'cv_wc_disable_admin_bar', 10, 1);

function cv_wc_disable_admin_bar($prevent_admin_access) {

    return false;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_prevent_admin_access', 'cv_wc_prevent_admin_access', 10, 1);

function cv_wc_prevent_admin_access($prevent_admin_access) {

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @kevin_cristiano Excellent! The woocommerce_prevent_admin_access solved the issue!!! However, I do not see what the woocommerce_disable_admin_bar filter does though.

Comment: Woo can also hide the admin bar for non administrators, or at least it did at one time :) things change and that may not be an issue any longer